# odata olingo: add custom parameters to URL

Tags: url, servlets, odata, olingo

I want to add some context paramters to my odata service. 
The parameters i want to include in the url as param (after the service name) so that the url can be used in excel

How would one be able to receive and parse any addition param supplied in the url before the odata service does it's thing?

(i'm using Olingo)

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom query options. See 5. Custom Query Options here: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/

In Olingo, the GetEntityUriInfo, PostEntityUriInfo etc interfaces define a getCustomQueryOptions method: https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata2/org/apache/olingo/odata2/api/uri/info/GetEntityUriInfo.html#getCustomQueryOptions--

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the scn blog about adding a custom annotation to metadata
Refer the link
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/02/adding-custom-annotation-and-labels-to-metadata/